# Error Handling in ActiveRecord Transactions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to create a row in both tickets and users table... I just need to know how to process in case the transaction fails.

```
@ticket.transaction do
    @ticket.save!
    @user.save!
end
    #if (transaction succeeded)
        #.....
    #else (transaction failed)
        #......
    #end
```

On a side note I'd just like to thank everyone who participates at stack overflow for helping a designer learn more programming... I appreciate the time you guys take out of your day to answer n00b questions like this :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you are using the save! method with a bang (exclamation point), the application will throw an exception when the save fails. You would then have to catch the exception to handle the failure.

```
begin
  @ticket.transaction do
    @ticket.save!
    @user.save!
  end
  #handle success here
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
   #handle failure here
end
```

Comment: A transaction like the one in the first snippet (without throwing exceptions), is not a Rails transaction at all.

A transaction like the one in the second snippet should rescue all exceptions (rescue => e), handle failure, and possibly raise the same exception again.

Comment: Sorry Ando, but it clearly is an ActiveRecord transaction, as evidenced by the method "transaction". The salient point of a transaction is that the first action (save ticket) is rolled back if the second fails. This was a very basic example for a new developer...obviously one would replace the comment with the failure handling. Thanks for sharing your perspective on error handling, but  the example comes from "Agile Web Development with Rails", as written by the initial author of Rails! So I would take exception at your characterization of something that doesn't throw an exception as not Rails

Comment: @MattMcKnight Ando has a point. Your first snippet is not correct because Rails will not rollback changes to the database. A rollback is only initiated if the code within the transaction raises an exception. Returning false will not rollback the database. So `@record.save` in a transaction is plain wrong.

Comment: One thing to add here is that you can raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback` in your transaction to force a rollback. This exception is not re-raised by Railse.

Comment: What if I'm not using save?

Comment: @fatuhoku - what are you using? there is also update! destroy! etc. The thing to remember is the ones with ! raise exceptions.

Comment: if anyone interested I've created TIL note to summarize different Do and Don't when it comes to rescue transactions based on this SO question https://blog.eq8.eu/til/rollback-rails-transaction-and-rescue-error-to-display-it.html

Answer (score 0):

i'm also a beginner, but i believe that you can check @ticket.errors and @user.errors and validate according to their responses

also the save method should return a boolean that determines if the save was successful